# argparse : ValueError when using --help or -h option with nargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

When using argparse I get this weird ValueError for help option.
All other options work fine. Only the help option is not working, which is weird.

Here is the error message:

```
chaudhary@localhost:~/code/python/logmein$ ./logmein.py --bla
Usage:  ./logmein.py  [filename <Default: .login.txt>] || [password] || [username password]
chaudhary@localhost:~/code/python/logmein$ ./logmein.py --boo
Usage:  ./logmein.py  [filename <Default: .login.txt>] || [password] || [username password]
chaudhary@localhost:~/code/python/logmein$ ./logmein.py -b
Usage:  ./logmein.py  [filename <Default: .login.txt>] || [password] || [username password]
chaudhary@localhost:~/code/python/logmein$ ./logmein.py -h
Unexpected Error: <class 'ValueError'>
Details: unsupported format character 'p' (0x70) at index 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./logmein.py", line 222, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "./logmein.py", line 158, in main
    args, otherthings = parser.parse_known_args()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 1737, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 1943, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 1883, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)


 File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 1811, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 1015, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 2339, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 2323, in format_help
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 276, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 206, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/argparse.py", line 293, in _format_usage
    usage = usage % dict(prog=self._prog)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'p' (0x70) at index 1
```

Here is my code

```
# Parse command line arguments
from argparse import ArgumentParser
usage = "%prog [-f credential_file]"
parser = ArgumentParser(usage=usage)
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", type=str, dest="file",
                    help="Use the specified file")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--logout", action='store_true', dest="logout",
                    help="Logout")
#parser.add_argument('otherthings', nargs='*')
#args = parser.parse_args()
args, otherthings = parser.parse_known_args()
argc = len(otherthings)

if args.file != None:
    username, password = parse_file_for_credential(args.file)
```

Now I can't find out why this ValueError comes and that too only for --help option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when argparse attempts to interpolate your `usage` string Python sees the following character sequence: `%p`.  Since `p` is not [a valid conversion flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), Python raises the `ValueError`.

You can generate this error yourself at the REPL:

```
>>> "This is valid: %s" % "magic"
"This is valid: magic"

>>> "This will raise a ValueError: %p" % "magic"
ValueError: unsupported format character 'p' (0x70)
```

The reason this is happening is because you use `%prog` rather than the correct `%(prog)s` (note the parenthesis around the key in `%s`).  Change `usage = "%prog [-f credential_file]"` to `usage = "%(prog)s [-f credential_file]"` as Rob suggests and everything will work.

#### Why does argparse use this formatting syntax?

argparse provides metadata like the program's name via *named* format arguments to allow the arguments to appear in any order, and to allow for repetition.  Positional arguments cannot be re-used and must appear in the same order as they are provided:

```
>>> "If I want another %s then I need to add another %s" % ("param", "placeholder")
"If I want another param then I need to add another placeholder"
# There is no way to change the order around to be
# "If I want another placeholder then I need to add another param"
# without changing the order of the parameters passed to `%`
```

while named arguments can be repeated and used in any order:

```
>>> s = "Any order, %(two)s / %(one)s. Repeats %(one)s / %(two)s are possible"
>>> s % {"one": "first", "two": "last"}
"Any order, last / first. Repeats first / last are possible"
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prog):

> > Note that the program name, whether determined from `sys.argv[0]` or from the `prog=` argument, is available to help messages using the `%(prog)s` format specifier.

Try `usage = "%(prog)s [-f credential_file]"`